# Como deixar uma TabPage invisível dentro de um TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Como posso deixar uma determinada TabPage invisível dentro de um TabControl ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deixar invisível é impossível, mas dá pra ter o mesmo efeito removendo e adicionando a `TabPage` ao `TabControl`:

```
tbControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);
tbControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
```

Answer (score 5):

É possível desvincular a `TabPage` do `TabControl` em questão através da propriedade `Parent`, sem precisar removê-la:

```
suaTabPage.Parent = null;
```

E para vincular, só indicar o `TabControl`:

```
suaTabPage.Parent = tbControl;
```